# Transparent text background in beamer

Tags: beamer, color, backgrounds

Recently – I believe due to Texlive update – the background of the title text on my beamer presentation started to be of solid color compared to being fully transparent before.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,t]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{default}
\title{Test}

\begin{document}
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{test.jpg}}
\frame[b]{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image: White blocks behind text]

How can I get rid of the white blocks so only the background image and text is visible?

Comment: There's no problem with MikTeX

Comment: After replacing your image I have no issues either on TeXLive 2018. No White areas. Exactly which TeXLive version are you using, and if relevant, which PDF viewer are you using?

Comment: It's [texlive 2018.48566-1 (arch)](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/texlive-core/) and zathura/mupdf; However the image in the post above was converted from pdf using imagemagick so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: There had been a bug recently. Can you tell us which beamer version you use?

Comment: "2018/09/02 v3.52 A class for typesetting presentations"; This version string?

Comment: @Pelipap Update should solve your problem.